# Help with this Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to get a collection of Students whose average grade (by adding each individual subject score and dividing by the amount of subjects) is above 55.

Since this year is 2011, I also need to calculate this field only for the 2011 records.

[image]

```
private void cmbGradeParalelo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StudentRepository studentRepo = new StudentRepository():
    dataGridView1.DataSource = studentRepo.FindAllStudents()
                                          .Where(s=>s.ScoreRecords.)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming every student may have multiple ScoreRecords, maybe try

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = studentRepo.FindAllStudents
                                      .Where(s=> s.ScoreRecords
                                                  .Where(r => r.Year == 2011)
                                                  .Average(r => r.FinalGrade) > 55)
```

Comment: That's great! But what would I do if FinalGrade isn't an automatically calculated field? I need to add all scores in First trimester and divide by amount.

Comment: You could use `(r.FirstTrimester + r.SecondTrimester + r.ThirdTrimester) / 3` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(s=>s.ScoreRecords.Year == 2011).Average(f => f.FinalGrade) > 55));
```

Comment: Ok, that solves the bit about getting only the 2011 records. What about iterating through each subject and getting scores?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia:  After I've finished my edit, it looks similar to Jens' answer.